# How to split operator and operands in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, split

My operators are: `=`, `>=`, `<=`, `>`, `<`
And my expression are as simple as the following samples:

```
string1 = string2
string1=string2
string1= string2
string1 =string2
string1>=string2
string1 >=string2
string1 >= string2
string1 <string2
...
```

I need to split any of the above expressions into three words and get a list filled with operators and the operand. e.g.

```
['string1', '>=', 'string2']
```

I tried to use `re.split` but got no suitable result. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
re.split('(\W+)', 'string1 >=string2')
```

Note that surrounding `\W+` with parenthesis will keep the literal you're splitting according to.

If you want to be specific and split only to the given strings, you can make a list of them and build a regex with `|` separating each.

Comment: Thank you. It returns `['string1', ' >=', 'string2']`. Is it possible to get `['string1', '>=', 'string2']` (trimmed words)?

Comment: @Meysam `[x.strip(' ') for x in re.split...]`

Comment: @Meysam or you can use `map(str.strip, re.split('(\W+)', 'string1 >=string2'))`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the last part of your answer?

Comment: @Meysam `|` in regex means "OR", so if you want to split according to `>=` or `=` or `>` you simply write `>=|=|>`. So in general, you can `|.join(list_of_regexes)`, this will limit to the use-cases you've mentioned.

Comment: `re.split('>=|=|>', 'string1 = string2')` returns `['string1 ', ' string2']` and `re.split('>=|=|>', 'string1 == string2')` returns `['string1 ', '', ' string2']`. Is it possible for both of them to return the operator as well? Like returning `['string1 ', '=', ' string2']` or `['string1 ', '==', ' string2']`

Comment: @Meysam try: `re.split('(==|>=|=)', 'string1 >=string2')`. Don't forget to surround with `()`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code that extracts the data, you may put the found elements in a list as you wish:

```
import re
lst = ['string1 = string2',
    'string1=string2',
    'string1= string2',
    'string1 =string2',
    'string1>=string2',
    'string1 >=string2',
    'string1 >= string2',
    'string1 <string2']
pat = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s*([<>=]{1,2})\s*(\w+)')
for e in lst :
    matches = pat.search(e)
    print matches.group(1), matches.group(2), matches.group(3)
```

output:

```
string1 = string2
string1 = string2
string1 = string2
string1 = string2
string1 >= string2
string1 >= string2
string1 >= string2
string1 < string2
```

Comment: Your regex will also match `string1 << string2` and `string1 <> string2` which contain illegal operators.

Comment: This is stricter: `pat = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s*(=|<=|>=|<|>)\s*(\w+)')`

Comment: Thank you both for comments. I assumed the input data is valid. Anyway, the stricter is the regex, the better it is.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `re.findall`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "string1>=string2"
>>> re.findall(r'\w+|[^\s\w]+', s)
['string1', '>=', 'string2']
>>> re.findall(r'\w+|[^\s\w]+', 'string1 = string2')
['string1', '=', 'string2']
>>> re.findall(r'\w+|[^\s\w]+', 'string1 >= string2')
['string1', '>=', 'string2']
>>> re.findall(r'\w+|[^\s\w]+', 'string1 <string2')
['string1', '<', 'string2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression in python to seperate numeric operators and operands. You might have to edit it slightly if u want to use on strings,but it will be easy if u know the rules and go through some examples in stackoverflow.

```
numlst = re.findall("[0-9]+|\+|\-|\*|\/|\(|\)",eqn)
```